# Solve $u_{tt}-u_{xx}-(2/x)u_x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

The hint in my textbook is that $w = ux$. I really don't know how to proceed. I have attempted questions like these previously, but never one with a variable coefficient. Any pointers?

I know we have to substitute $u$ with $w/x$ but I am unsure as to how that substitution will work (i.e. what will $u_{tt}$ be?

Comment: I know. I want to know exactly HOW that substitution works. Sorry for lack of clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(x,t) = \frac{w(x,t)}{x}.$ So $u_t = \frac{w_t(x,t)}{x}$ and $u_{tt} = \frac{w_{tt}(x,t)}{x}$.

Similarly $u_x = \frac{w_x}{x} - \frac{w}{x^2},$ etc.